# IISNode is not loading the dependencies

Tags: node.js, azure, iisnode

I am trying to host this node.js app https://github.com/Lapple/ErrorBoard on Azure website and to start with I created a node.js application in WebMatrix.

As the application says, eb.js is the entry point of the app and I set that in web.config as well but it always says that  # has no method 'listen' and breaks at Line no. 6 in eb.js.

I think the dependent files are not being loaded where **server** object is defined. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: How are you deploying your app to the Azure We Site?

Comment: I published via WebMatrix, but it is not working my local machine either.